# Router to handle 300 connections and run a web server

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wireless-router, webserver, dd-wrt

Is there a router that can handle 300 concurrent connections and run a lightweight web server?

It seems most home routers wouldn't be able to handle that kind of load. It would be nice to be able to reflash the router so that we can use something like DD-WRT on it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a router that can handle 300 concurrent connections and run a
>   lightweight web server?

There are a few issues with your question. If you understand how web servers work, 300 concurrent connections is something that only a massive site would deal with.

Web server connections are asynchronous and most small websites barely get 20-30 connections per second.  A connection is made from a client, content is sent from them server to the client & then the connection is basically dead.

For example, when you loaded this page outside of AJAX & perhaps web sockets set for the Stack Exchange site, the “heavy lifting” happened on the first load of the page. Past that, this content you are reading is now stagnant. Simple websites do not stream content. They just serve content & browsers download them.

I have dealt with moderately high traffic websites & they float between 60 to 90 connections per second.

So 300 connections per second is just insanely high and the chances of a simple/cheap router handling 300 connections per second is zilch. If you are truly dealing with 300 connections per second on a web server you are looking at a high capacity web server. Not something you pay $40 for and then install OpenWRT—or something similar—on.

Comment: I said they don't disconnect from the router. And as for the web server, can I not set keep-alive to a timeout of a couple hours? Say I just want to have 300 people connect and be served content for 2 hours.

Comment: Looks like firefox defaults to 115 seconds maximum for keep alive connections. Oh well. How many machines do you think it would take to support 300 people trying to get content (mostly text) from a web server for 2 hours?

Comment: @mdenton8 Instead of creating a huge comment thread, it'd be better to edit and clarify your original question (although we don't do shopping recommendations…). The way I understand it you have two issues: 1) offering WiFi connectivity to 300 clients, and 2) offering a web server that may have to deal with 300 concurrent connections. Even better would be to explain what actual problem you're trying to solve or what the use case for said web server / router is.